# Input in java - preparing for an interview

Tags: java

I will have an interview for job as a junior java developer. I have no
professional experience in programming, which means I never made any
application for someone. I was asked to prepare for the
interview some example: a kind of calculator application. They put 2 conditions:

1. API should be:

   ```
   public int calculate(String action, int a, int b)
   ```
2. example:

input:    multiply 5 4
output:    20

What do they mean by API and input/output? I always inputed simple data as String[] args Should I have main class like
this (by main class I mean class which communicates with a user)?

```
class MainClass {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      String action = args[0];
      int a = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      int b = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
      SomeClass calculator = new SomeClass();

      // Is this using of API?
      int result = calculator.calculate(action, a, b);

      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

What about other methods of input and output (like Scanner, InputStream, Console)? What would you expect if you conducted such interview?

Comment: If you dont know this, you prolly shouldnt be a Junior Level Dev.... at least in that position/language.

Comment: I will say though, that yes.  you are correct for for the most part.   if you need to make an API, you would need to have a class, and in many cases, overload the functions such that multiple input types are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the method `public int calculate( String action, int a, int b )`.

[API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Api) stands for Application Programming Interface. It is more or less the available functions, methods, and classes that can be used elsewhere. You don't have to worry about how the data was inputted into the program, it could be hardcoded, read from a user, read from a file, etc.

Also note, a lot of time, with these seemingly simple problems, they are looking for safe code. That is how does it react to bad input, eg `calculate( "invalid operation", 2, 1 );` In this scenario, since you cannot return an error code you probably want to throw an `Exception` of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

API ([WikiPedia def](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)) is not only related in Java to the "main" method, except (maybe) if you are developing a CLI (Command Line Interface) tool. API is the set of public services, classes and methods available to third parties in your application or component.

So, your approach seems correct because as CLI tool it fits the interface they are request for, but if you simply implements a class with that method, `calculate(...)` is also correct, in this case, think about it as a "math library" that needs to fit that API.

I think that the important thing in this case is how to implement that method, not the API concept.

Answer (score 1):

API stands for application programming interface, it's just the methods your application should provide for other apps to consume. In any case, your main method should only be used to test your API.  If I were interviewing you I would expect a full class implementation with methods like add, multiply, etc. with their inputs (two numbers, for example) and a class to test it, with a main method.